# Overwrite method in Filter

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have in my database a table Test with the following fields :

```
 id | name
 1  | YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcw==
 2  | fghfghgcm5hbCBwbGVhcw==
```

Name is hashed using base64. In my model I can overwrite this method:

```
public function getName() {
        return base64_decode($this->getName);
}
```

and in function save:

```
$this->setName(base64_encode($this->getName));
```

this is working OK, but i have big problem with filter in admin generator. If i type for filter name exist NAME, for example "stackoverflow" then this make query with "stackoverflow" instead of base64_encode('stackoverflow'). Is possible overwrite this? If yes, how?

I use Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.

Comment: whats the point in saving names in base64?

Comment: this is example. i have overwrite method in filter

Comment: You must have a setName() method to encode the value in the first place: "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE name = '".$this->setName($name)."'"; but as KingCrunch syas, "what's the point in saving names in base64?"

Comment: but where i can edit these query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overload `doBuildQuery` in the `sfFormFilterDoctrine` subclass for that field, such that it queries by the encoded value.

http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormFilterDoctrine.class.php#L148

EDIT: alternately, you could overload `addTextQuery`. Either way, explain the business logic clearly in a comment

Answer (score -1):

Try to look at SHA1 encrypting. Request will look like `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE name=SHA1(".$myNameFromAdmin.");`

And one more: You needn't `public function getName()` — that's alias for base64_decode()

Comment: SHA1 is not encryption... it's a hashing algorithm (and not a good one either), and therefore not reversible. OP's post clearly indicates (by the very existence of his getName() method) that he wants a reversible encoding, though quite why he wants to encode something like this is unknown

Comment: I have mistake. Twice :( Thank You.

Comment: Why is this tagged for symfony and doctorine? it has nothing to do with either.

Comment: because i use Symfony and Doctrine. I would like make this in FILTER Symfony

Comment: I use NetBeans, Firefox and Windows7. Should I mark all my posts with it?